# Manipulating PDF file, Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, pdf-generation

I have pdf page I would like to print/save from the C# windows forms application, however i would like to modify the file before that in adding a final comments page written by the user (only text).

Can somebody please point me to the a simple pdf library that does this exact thing in a simple code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/) is worth a look

Comment: I'm studying the technology, but so far it seems great. 
I'll let you know when it all works find (mark this as an answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at PDF Sharp: http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=40 (currently offline apparently)

Another option is (paid version) PDF Metamorphosis: http://www.sautin.com/products/components/pdfmetamorphosis/index.php.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Standard .NET classes don't directly support handling PDF Document format. You need to use a programming SDK (like leadtools or itextsharp). Since I am not familiar with itextsharp, I will talk about my experience with leadtools functions. This SDK supports loading PDF files, extract text and save it  back as PDF document format.
I am suggesting the following approach using lead tools functions:
- Load the PDF file as image (all objects (Text, Images, hyperlinks, etc.) inside the PDF file will be rasterized as one image).
- Pass the rasterized image to one of leadtools OCR engines. Lead OCR engines give the ability to define a zone on the image, recognize the text, edit it and then save it back as PDF document format.

You can find more information here:
http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/31677/ShowPost.aspx

Comment: Thanks for responding, hope it will be useful to people with similar question

Unfortunately that question was in 2010, I have changed 4 jobs since then, I have no use for this info.

Comment: Thank you Rakesh for mentioning our library. However, the old solution you suggested is not the best way to do it now, since the newer versions of LEADTOOLS have many PDF features that can accomplish this in a faster way. For example, to append a page to an existing PDF file, you no longer need to load the pages as raster bitmaps or perform OCR. You can simply use the [PDFFile.MergeWith method.](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/pdf/pdffile-mergewith.html)